# Handlebars partials name in a json

Tags: javascript, templates, partials

I have that handlebars template :

```
{{#each slides}}
    <div class="slide">
        {{> }}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Where there is {{> }} , I want to render a partial whos name comes from the data associated with the template.
For example, this data :

```
{
    slides : [
        {
            id : "id",
            slidePartial : "1-textleft"
        },

        {
            id : "id1",
            slidePartial : "2-textright"
        }
    ]
}
```

The slidePartial would be the partial dynamically loaded so we would have something like :

```
    <div class="slide">
        {{> 1-textleft}}
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        {{> 1-textright}}
    </div>
```

I've read that it's not possible because the template is compiled before, so how can I do this ? If it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution via this great Handlebars helper : [Conditional partials in Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484977/conditional-partials-in-handlebars)

So, in my main template i have something like :

```
{{#compare slidePartial '1-textleft' operator='==='}}
  {{> 1-textleft this.content}}
{{/compare}}

{{#compare slidePartial '2-textright' operator='==='}}
  {{> 1-textright this.content}}
{{/compare}}
...
```